# Custom 404 error page in cPanel is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I've added a custom 404 page in cpanel - Advanced - Error Pages. And a file with the name 404.shtml is in the root of my website now. In the .htaccess I've added: ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml (ErrorDocument 404 /public_html/404.shtml (direct path) also does not do the trick)

And if I call the file direct by going to https://.example.com/404.shtml it is showing. But when I type a page that is not existing, I still get the default Apache Not Found page.

Any clue what I am missing here?

Comment: "I've added a custom 404 page in cpanel" - What did this do? Just create the `404.shtml` file I guess? Are `.htaccess` files enabled? (Is this a shared server?)

Comment: Yea, it just created the 404.shtml file.
.htaccess files are enabled, it is a personal VPS server - not shared

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? You have a dot before the domain name - is that just a typo? What is the exact wording of the "Apache Not Found Page" - does it state that ... "in addition a custom errordocument could not be found" - or something like that?

Comment: Your comment made me thinking and started to dig in the .htaccess file. To make a long story short, removing this line shows the correct 404 page

RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ router.php?router_page=search_results&name_seo=$1 [L,QSA]

Only... I am a bit afraid to remove it, since I am not 100% sure what effect it has..

Update: well... it does a lot... removing that line and most pages show the 404 page

Comment: That line looks like the "router" that drives your web application?! What CMS/platform are you using? Yes, you don't want to remove that. However, that would also imply that what you were seeing wasn't the "default Apache Not Found page" - or maybe it was just one that looked like it?

Comment: Hi, yea. seems it needs to be set in the router somehow? I am using chameleonscript - based on php

Comment: Yes, it would seem to suggest that the 404 is generated by your web application (PHP) - not Apache. PHP has no way to communicate back to the Apache ErrorDocument  - so setting this in `.htaccess` will have no effect. Sorry, I'm not familiar with chameleonscript.